# How do I name my row in a c# data table?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a DataTable and I add Columns programatically (therefore, there isn't a set number of columns):

```
MyTable.Columns.Add(Value.name, typeof(double));
```

I then add empty rows to the table for the data:

```
MyTable.Rows.Add(0);
```

I want to add a row labels, such as "price", "quantity", "bid", etc
If I add these the way I know how, I need to know the number of columns we will have

How do I code this to be more robust, where the number of columns isn't static?
Thanks

Comment: You can add columns whenever you want.

Comment: The number of columns is dynamically chosen at run time... I am concerned with labeling rows, not columns

Comment: You mean to add label is to find the row by key or for displaying?

Comment: for display purposes
We wish to display the name of the row on the displayed data table

Comment: Which control you use for binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make to have a header row.
Tables store *data*, not presentation.

You should set your columns' `Name`s.

Comment: This is the standard convention in this given application, but thanks anyway.....

Comment: @DolemiteMofo: That is a _horrible_ convention.  That means that all of your row counts will be off, you can't use constraints properly, you can't use non-string data-types, and _many_ other problems.  **Do not do that**.  Especially because databases are unordered.

Answer (score 0):

You may access columns in the Columns collection.

I will demonstrate the itteration using a list of strings:

```
List<string> columns = new List<string>();
columns .Add("price");
columns .Add("quantity");
columns .Add("bid");
columns .Add("price");

foreach(string columnName in columns)
{
    if(MyTable.Columns[columnName] == null)
    {
        //Col does not exist so add it:
        MyTable.Columns.Add(columnName);
    } 
}
```

Notice that the list has the column `price` twice, but it will only add it once.

```
public DataTable GetDataTable() 
{ 
    var dt = new DataTable(); 
    dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(string)); // dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));    
    dt.Columns["Id"].Caption ="my id"; 
    dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string)); 
    dt.Columns.Add("Job", typeof(string)); 
    dt.Columns.Add("RowLabel", typeof(string));
    dt.Rows.Add(GetHeaders(dt)); 
    dt.Rows.Add(1, "Janeway", "Captain", "Label1"); 
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "Seven Of Nine", "nobody knows", "Label2"); 
    dt.Rows.Add(3, "Doctor", "Medical Officer", "Label3"); 
    return dt; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response...
I don't think I explained my need well enough...

Say we have a sandwich shop. 
The columns are for bread, meat, cheese, lettuce, etc.... 
The rows are things like cost of item, number in stock, etc

The number of columns (here sandwich components) are chosen at run time, but regardless of the number of components, we want the names of the rows to be the same

Currently, we can construct the table just fine, but the row labels are blank.... how do we label these rows?

Comment: public DataTable GetDataTable()
{
    var dt = new DataTable();   
    dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(string)); // dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns["Id"].Caption ="my id";  
    dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Job", typeof(string));
    dt.Rows.Add(GetHeaders(dt));
    dt.Rows.Add(1, "Janeway", "Captain");
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "Seven Of Nine", "nobody knows");
    dt.Rows.Add(3, "Doctor", "Medical Officer");
    return dt;
}

This is how I know how to do it, when the number of columns is set in stone pre runtime... how do i do it for a dynamic #of cols

Comment: I would like to see an example of expected input data and output format.

Comment: http://my.jetscreenshot.com/13957/20130916-0zhx-35kb.jpg
(column names edited in paint)

say, the number of columns was chosen at run time, how would I get this row to be labled "number left in stock," instead of that arrow, regardless of how many columns would be chosen at run time

Comment: I would add another column in the end called "Label" and i would fill that.

Comment: How does that get my ROW labeled? I am confused?

Comment: I don't think you can do what you are asking unless you somehow create a custom control.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the DataTable members.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx

```
var columnCount = MyTable.Columns.Count;
```